# How to replace multiple substrings at the same time

Tags: python, substring

I have a string like

```
a = "X1+X2*X3*X1"
b = {"X1":"XX0","X2":"XX1","X0":"XX2"}
```

I want to replace the substring 'X1,X2,X3' using dict b.

However, when I replace using the below code,

```
for x in b:
    a = a.replace(x,b[x])
print(a)
```

> 'XXX2+XX1*X3'

Expected result is  `XX0 + XX1*X3*XX0`

I know it is because the substring is replaced in a loop, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Are + and * the only characters separating your elements?

Comment: you are updating the string too often. the easiest way to do this is with the `re` (regex) module.

Comment: See _Split by multiple different delimiters_ at https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-split-rsplit-splitlines-re/

Comment: keys and values are "incested"... thats why you got a "strange" result

Comment: you should use `print(a)` inside `for`-loop to see what you get after every `replace`. And you should see that after first `replace` you have `XX0 + ....` but later `"X0":"XX2"` will treats `XX0 + ... ` as normal `X0` and it will put `XX2`.

Comment: problem it that old variables `X0`, `X1`, `X2` are similar to new variables `XX0`, `XX1`, `XX2` but if you would use litte different variables ie. `XX!0`, `XX!1`, `XX!2` and use your loop then you could get `XX!0 + XX!1 * X3 * XX!0` and you would need only `replace('!', '')` to get expected `XX0 + XX1 * X3 * XX0`

Comment: There is no pattern in original string, I just want to replace only once in the original string.

Comment: the patterns arise in the cycle when you update `a`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a pattern with `'|'` then search in dictionary transform like below.

Try this:

```
import re
a = "X1+X2*X3*X1"
b = {"X1":"XX0","X2":"XX1","X0":"XX2"}

pattern = re.compile("|".join(b.keys()))
out = pattern.sub(lambda x: b[re.escape(x.group(0))], a)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
'XX0+XX1*X3*XX0'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `repl` parameter of `re.sub`:

```
import re
re.sub('X\d', lambda x: b.get(x.group(), x.group()), a)
```

output:

```
'XX0+XX1*X3*XX0'
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is beacuse you are replacing the same string multiple times, so behind the scenes (or between the iterations) there are a few more switches in the middle that you probably don't see (unless debugging this code).
Please note that dictionary keys are not ordered, so you cannot assume what's replaced when.
I suggest you use [template](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings)

Edit: newer versions of python do preserve insertion order - [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)

Answer (score 1):

With just built-in functions. The given `b` dictionary contains cycles between keys and values, so used the `f-string` notation to perform the substitutions. To escape the `{}` one should double them `{{}}`, used for repeated substitution. The `enumerate` is needed to get unique keys in the new dictionary, so no more cycles.

```
a = "X1+X2*X3*X1"
b = {"X1":"XX0","X2":"XX1","X0":"XX2"}

new_dict = {}
for i, k in enumerate(b):
    sub_format =  f'{k}' + f'{i}'
    new_dict[sub_format] = b[k]
    a = a.replace(k, f'{{{sub_format}}}')

print(a.format(**new_dict))
```

Output

```
XX0+XX1*X3*XX0
```